# Windows 2008 R2 - Time change on domain

Tags: windows, hyper-v, timezone

The time on my domain is 50 minutes behind the correct time. I would like to change the time on all the servers in the domain to reflect the correct time. Here is the setup:

Two physical machines with four Hyper-V guests each.

Node1 - first physical machine, Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter

Node2 - second physical machine, Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter

DC1 - first AD server, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

DC2 - second AD server, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Web1 - first web server, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Web2 - second web server, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

App1 - first Sharepoint App server, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

App2 - second Sharepoint App server, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

DB1 - Database server on Hyper-V cluster, Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter

App3 - Standalone .net app server, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

How should I proceed with the change in time on all these servers? Prompt advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: which dc holds your PDC Emulator role?

Answer (score 6):

The domain controller holding the PDC emulator role is the master time server for the domain.

Follow this guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786897(v=ws.10).aspx

All the rest will begin to synchronize. Be prepared for authentication failures as Kerberos only tolerates a 5 minute time difference. Plenty of publicly available documentation on how to configure and verify all of this.

Comment: +1. Please don't change the time on all your servers individually. They should be syncing with a DC in their site; and all DCs in the domain should be syncing to the PDCe, the PDCe in each domain should be syncing to the PDCe in the forest root domain, and finally that PDCe should by syncing to a reliable external time source like pool.ntp.org. If that is not the case, then you need to address that problem first.

Comment: You actually reminded me of a good point. Be sure that all your subnets are defined in sites and services so that this hierarchy is followed!

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff Over 5 minutes works just fine these days, actually.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956627